# Passing an array of cv::Mat to a function in C

Tags: arrays, function, vector

I am having this problem for a few days now and I can not find a way around it.

I'm trying to store an array of cv::Mats and the way I was doing this so far was by having a a
`std::vector<cv::Mat> store_frames(32);` and every time I was just copying the new frames to their location with `frame.copyTo(store_frames[i])`.
This works fine if it's inside main but if I want to pass it to a function and do the same thing it's not good anymore.
I did not have the same problem with simple mats. I was just declaring them globally inside a header
`cv::Mat frame;`

And if I had a function:

```
void function( cv::Mat &f1 ) {
..
f1.at<float>(10,10) += 100;
..
}
```

Then call the function `function(frame);`
All the changes inside the function would be saved. So let's say I will have something like

```
...
for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
function(frame);
std::cout<<frame.at<float>(10,10)<<' ';
}
```

The output (assuming the initial value of frame.at(10,10) would be 
`100 200 300 400 500`

**The problem** now is that I can not do the same thing with std::vector store_frames . First of all if I try to declare it in the header the same way `std::vector<cv::Mat> store_frames(32);` I get an error on number 32 saying `Error: expected a type specifier`. And if I just say `std::vector<cv::Mat> store_frames;` then it won't know it's size. I saw somewhere people calling `store_frames.resize` I've tried to do that, but I get an error saying `this declaration has no storage class or type specifier`. I've looked up the internet for solutions, but didn't find any. I know the question itself might sound stupid, but I'm new to this and I don't know much.

So my questions is how do I declare this vector so that it would be possible to pass it to a function, modify it inside and the modifications would be saved?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

1. declared it `std::vector<cv::Mat> store_frame;` in the header and `store_frame.resize(32);` in the source code.
2. use `std::vector<cv::Mat> store_frames(32);` in the source code.

ps: I just added this as the comment. :)